# Difference between su user - and su - user

Tags: su

What is the difference between the two below?

```
$ su user -
```

and

```
$ su - user
```

Comment: http://www.linfo.org/su.html

Answer (score 0):

"su - user" will create a login environment for the user.

"su user -" is arguably not a valid syntax (depending on your version), and is probably going to be interpreted as synonymous with su user (which does not create a login environment)